# arduino wifi configuration without Arduino ide

Tags: arduino, wifi

I want to change the Wifi configuration that is hardcoded in the sketch file without having to open the Arduino IDE when I move to a new location.
Any suggestions?

The line which gives the `ssid` and password in the Arduino sketch is as follows.

```
char ssid[] = "yourNetwork";      //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "secretPassword";   // your network password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what ever text editor you want to change those lines but you need to compile and upload your sketch for the changes to take effect.

If you don't want to do that, you can use the [Arduino-Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) and run everything from the command line.

Or you can adapt your program to be able to set those by hand with serial communication. But you'll still need the Arduino IDE Monitor to talk to the Arduino.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save data to eeprom instead of into variables. eeprom can be changed when the Arduino is running, variables need to be recompiled.

With eeprom you can use Serial to send new values at any time. This means that you would only need a usb cable and terminal/serial monitor to change network settings.